# Unable to call WCF service with wsHttpBinding from Iphone

Tags: android, ios, iphone, wcf, wcf-binding

I have designed a WCF service for Authentication of the new user for both `Iphone` and `Android`. Initially I was using `basciHttpBinding` and my service was working fine for Iphone, but 15-20 days back I have changed the configuration and now I am using `wsHttpBinding`. Now I am unable to call my service from `Iphone` with `wsHttpBinding` but it is working well for `Android`. I heard that `wsHttpBinding` not work for `Iphone`. Can anyone please suggest me what configuration should I have to make in my web.config to work it for `Iphone` as well.

**Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
      <!--<section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler, Spring.Web"/>-->
      <section name="parsers" type="Spring.Context.Support.NamespaceParsersSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <spring>
    <parsers>
      <parser type="Spring.Data.Config.DatabaseNamespaceParser, Spring.Data"/>
      <parser type="Spring.Transaction.Config.TxNamespaceParser, Spring.Data"/>
    </parsers>
    <context>
      <!--<resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>-->
      <!--<resource uri="assembly://TA.Service/TA.Service.Config/DynamicConnection.xml"/>-->
      <resource uri="~/DynamicConnection.xml"/>
      <resource uri="assembly://TA.Service/TA.Service.Config/Dao.xml"/>
      <!--<resource uri="~/Dao.xml"/>-->
      <!--<resource uri="~/Config/Web.xml"/>-->
      <!--<resource uri="assembly://CB.Service/CB.Service/Services.xml"/>-->
    </context>
  </spring>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Spring.Data.NHibernate.Support.OpenSessionInViewModule.SessionFactoryObjectName" value="NHibernateSessionFactory"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myBehavior">
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0">
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="TA.Service.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior"
          bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" name="testendpoint" contract="TA.Service.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to test your service using SoapUI, it it gives proper results on SoapUI or any other soap testing tool then its an issue at client end which is your IPhone client development site.

You can get free soap ui from the following url.
http://www.soapui.org/

Thanks,
Gaurav